# Understanding VS's ability to create database on first run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, ef-code-first

I'm working with a (.net4 / mvc3 ) solution file downloaded (from a reputable source) where a connection string exists in web.config but I don't see explicit instructions to create the database and there's no included '.mdf'. The first time I build I got a runtime error regarding lack of permissions to CREATE database. So I created a blank db and made sure the string referenced a SQL user that had .dbo/owner rights to the db just created.

But subsequent builds don't seem to execute that same initialize db script - where ever that's stored.

Where is this 'first use' convention for creating databases documented?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a feature of Entity Framework Code First. I am not sure what you are looking for exactly, but searching for "EF Code First Initialization Strategy" might help.

For instance read this article: [EF Code First DB Initialization Using Web.Config](http://randypatterson.com/index.php/2011/11/12/ef-code-first-db-initialization-using-web-config/)

Comment: The project is Code First - the only reason it failed on my first run is the Connection String specified a username/password, which I created but didn't grant 'createdb' powers. thx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Entity Framework, which allows you to create the database from an instance of an `ObjectContext` object, which is used in any of the three approaches in EF (database-, model- and code-first).

Look for a line that actually calls `ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()`. If one of the supported ADO.NET provides is used (SQL Server or SQL Server CE 4.0) this will generate the required SQL Statements. Assuming the classic Northwind example, you might find something like that:

```
NorthwindContext context = new NorthwindContext();
if (!context.DatabaseExists())
{
    context.CreateDatabase();
}
```

If this is in fact a code-first application, "lalibi" is right about the initialization strategy which by default doesn't require you to explicitly create the database. (But my guess is, that it actually uses a statement internally very similar to mine).